# When does Eclipse copy resources to the output folder?

Tags: java, eclipse

I noticed that "sometimes" the resources i put into a source folder in my Eclipse project will not be copied to the output folder ("bin") immediately.
E.g. i change a properties file using the eclipse editor and save... and "bin" still has the old version.

Does anyone know what exactly triggers the copying (and how i can trigger that from a plugin)?
I thought it happened automatically when a resource changes.

-- EDIT --

To clarify what i meant by triggering it from a plugin: I have a plugin that depends on up to date resources in the output folder, but apparently the resources are outdated when my plugin is called. And that's why i need to better understand what happens and how i can force it when i need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **Bug** in almost all Eclipse versions, it happens without any reason. My eclipse 3.5.2 and 3.6.2 both meet this problem in someday. In my case, I need to copy modified .clj clojure source files to classes directory for immediate effection in a web app, now I have to set /src before /classes in CLASSPATH of web appserver startup script, It's solve my problem temporarily.

Comment: Since no one can explain it, i'll file it as "bug". Would be great though if we could find an official eclipse bug report.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't add the resource through eclipse (but for instance through the windows explorer), eclipse wont notice some changes until you refresh your project/folder. (right click in the packater explorer for instance).

After it notices the change it will copy it to the output folder when you build (often this is done automatically upon changes)

Comment: it's the "often" part that bothers me, since it doesn't happen during build phase in my test environment

Comment: If you're building an Eclipse plug-in, you can do a refresh from the plug-in.  Take a look at the IProject interface.

Comment: @Stroboskop: For Java projects its a setting in the build menu, which is on by default. For other projects it depends on the type of project and the plugin.

Comment: But wouldn't a "refresh" only synchronize with the filesystem and not copy the resources from source to output folder?

Comment: I'd guess its officially in the automatic build that happens afterward that they get copied, but the effect is the same, the folders get updated.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thirler said, if you don't add the resource through Eclipse, it may not notice the files until you refresh your project. However, if the Refresh/Clean doesn't work (in my case, it didn't), you have to add the files to the folder structure IN ECLIPSE.

Just drag the file from the folder where it is in the file system using Finder/Windows Explorer, drop it into the same folder in Eclipse's Project Explorer (Eclipse will ask for overwriting, just say yes) and Voila!

EDIT:
An easier way is to just navigate into the folder using Project Explorer and then Refresh (F5).

Answer (score 1):

There is an Eclipse setting `Java > Compiler > Building > Output folder > Filtered resources`.

[image]

For unknown reasons, this was set to `*.launch,*.testsuite,*.deploy,*.location,*.execution,*.datapool,*.artifact,*.html,*.svg` in my workspace (while the default seems to be just `*.launch`). This was the reason, why my Eclipse constantly refused to copy a classpath resource `index.html`.

Late response, but I just stumbled over this question but non of the answers helped me to convince Eclipse to do its job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it happens when you build the project. You don't need a plug-in, you just need to tell eclipse to do a build of the project.

Comment: you need to have 'build automatically' checked in the project menu for it to do it by itself. If you do, and it still doesn't do it, you may need to add the folder containing the file to the build path. The fact that you said the output folder contains the 'old' version suggests that is it on the build path and was copied there at some point. But if you just added it, and there's no 'old' version you may need to refresh the project to see if it was moved in the output folder as well

Comment: That's not it. The output folder gets updated occasionally. e.g. when i do a clean or when the workspace is launched. The file has been in the same location, was edited using eclipse and my Java sources in the same project are built and copied automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I imported an Eclipse project as a whole, including both `src` and `bin` directories. The fix is to `Clean` the project: `Project` -> `Clean...` -> select your project and press `Clean`. This should re-build the project and properly locate the resources needed.