# Resource file copied to output dir but not read by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I got an XML file in the root of src, which is outputted in the bin folder along with the compiled classes. How can I tell Eclipse to put in the classpath all future files that will reside in bin root's folder?

I don't see such an option. I am allowed to define output dir, whether copy or not folders from source, but I thought output's root was in the classpath.

Or is this an anormal behavior and I should be seeing it?

Thanks!

EDIT:

bin folder does not show up in Project view, even if I select Java ouput folders in the customize View. It shows in Navigator but it does not have the option to add to build path.

When editing Build path, I can select it as the output folder. I also checked projects metadata, it seems  is there

Comment: are you using Maven project?

Comment: No, I am just running a plain Java app, so everything in src gets copied to bin when compiling, but fails when running (only the non .class files). Should I add bin to buildpath as if it were the classpath?

Comment: Show us the code how you're accessing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry it was hibernate's thing.

It throws a generic message that file is not there, but if you pick another file in the bin's root, it's read. So either hibernate has some special considerations as a different classloader or basepath or they really need to change the meaning of the exception...

My apologize for not adverting a basic double-checking was obviously one possiblity.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Project properties and add your bin folder to the build path

Comment: So should be both build path and classpath associated to Eclipse's buildpath? I guessed that there must be a different var when compiling and running. Doesn't this make my compile environment dependant of the bin path which is not needed? Could it have this some relation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254768/when-does-eclipse-copy-resources-to-the-output-folder?rq=1?

Comment: Anyway, I don't know why or whether is it expected, but my bin folder is not shown in neither Package and Project Explorer to right-click it.